# How to attach a div to input value in rendered list?

Tags: javascript

I need to append a div to the input value in the list so I can add a style class to the div and move the input value text further to the right. This is the only way I can think of to style the input value text. Can this be done? Is there a better way to do it? Here is what I have so far. I am trying to avoid using innerHTML.
Note: If you uncomment the dummy text in the html snippet you will see what I am trying to accomplish.

```js
const todoForm = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoItemsList = document.querySelector('.todo-items');

let todos = [];


todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addTodo(todoInput.value);
});

function addTodo(input) {
  if (input !== '') {
    const todo = {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: input,
      completed: false,
    };
    todos.push(todo);
    renderTodos(todos);
    todoInput.value = '';
  }
}

function addCheckbox() {
  const checkBox = (cb = document.createElement('input'));
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cb.class = 'checkbox';
  cb.checked = false;
}

function renderTodos(todos) {
  // run through each item inside todos
  todos.forEach((item) => {
    addCheckbox();
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // textDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // textDiv.class = 'text-container';
    li.setAttribute('class', 'item');
    li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);
    li.appendChild(cb);
    li.append(item.name);
    // li.appendChild(textDiv);
    li.append(deleteButton);
    todoItemsList.append(li);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hsl(194, 100%, 70%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  color: hsl(214, 11%, 13%);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size: 3rem;
}


/* To Do Form */

.todo-form {
  margin: 40px 0px;
}

.todo-input {
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-items {
  min-width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Item style */

.item {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: hsl(348, 93%, 56%);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* border-radius: 7px; */
  /* padding: 2px 5px; */
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.text-container {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>

  <form class="todo-form">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="add a todo item">
    <button type="submit" class="add=button">Add</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="todo-items">
    <!--- dummy item --->
    <!--<li class="item" data-key="1594003133171">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
                Get on schedule
                <button class="delete-button">x</button>-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to clear the HTML of `todoItemsList` before writing to it again.  At the top of `renderTodos` add `renderTodos.innerHTML = ''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were encountering was happening because you were trying to set a class name using `element.class = 'classname'`, when the correct syntax is `element.classList.add('classname')`. I also found some other error and corrected:

- because you're always iterating through the array `todos`, you need to clear the list each time you write to it
- the `x` wasn't showing up in the button so I added it.

```js
const todoForm = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoItemsList = document.querySelector('.todo-items');

let todos = [];

todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addTodo(todoInput.value);
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('checkbox')) {
    if (e.target.checked) e.target.closest('.item').classList.add('checked')
    else e.target.closest('.item').classList.remove('checked');
  }
})

function addTodo(input) {
  if (input !== '') {
    const todo = {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: input,
      completed: false,
    };
    todos.push(todo);
    renderTodos(todos);
    todoInput.value = '';
  }
}

function renderTodos(todos) {
  // clear list 
  todoItemsList.innerHTML = ''
  // run through each item inside todos
  todos.forEach((item) => {
    // checkbox
    let cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.classList.add('checkbox');
    cb.checked = false;
    // delete button
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
    deleteButton.innerText = 'x';

    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('item');
    if (item.completed === true) {
      li.classList.add('checked')
      cb.checked = true;
    }
    li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);
    li.appendChild(cb);
    li.append(item.name);
    li.append(deleteButton);
    todoItemsList.append(li);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hsl(194, 100%, 70%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  color: hsl(214, 11%, 13%);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size: 3rem;
}


/* To Do Form */

.todo-form {
  margin: 40px 0px;
}

.todo-input {
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-items {
  min-width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Item style */

.item {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: hsl(348, 93%, 56%);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* border-radius: 7px; */
  /* padding: 2px 5px; */
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.text-container {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <form class="todo-form">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="add a todo item">
    <button type="submit" class="add=button">Add</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="todo-items"></ul>
</div>
```

Here's a more concise version, which may or may not be helpful to you

```js
const todoForm = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoItemsList = document.querySelector('.todo-items');

let todos = [];

todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (todoInput.value.trim() ==='') return;
  todos.push({id: Date.now(), name: todoInput.value.trim(), completed: false});
  todoItemsList.innerHTML = todos.map(todo => `
  <li class="item" data-key="${todo.id}">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
      ${todo.name}
      <button class="delete-button">x</button>
      </li>`).join('');
  todoInput.value = '';
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hsl(194, 100%, 70%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  color: hsl(214, 11%, 13%);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size: 3rem;
}


/* To Do Form */

.todo-form {
  margin: 40px 0px;
}

.todo-input {
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-items {
  min-width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Item style */

.item {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: hsl(348, 93%, 56%);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* border-radius: 7px; */
  /* padding: 2px 5px; */
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.text-container {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <form class="todo-form">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="add a todo item">
    <button type="submit" class="add=button">Add</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="todo-items"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you to His Majesty.

Comment: :) -- I also added a pared down version to my answer in case it's of interest.

Comment: I appreciate that! I did originally have innerHTML and it worked ok, but I refactored in order not to use that. The only reason is I heard it is a security issue. I am a beginner at Javascript so I am still learning this stuff.

Comment: I have one more related question if you don't mind. Am I on the right track doing this condition https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/gOWLjVE if I want to add a a strike through line when item gets checked? I can't seem to get it to work and don't understand where to put the condition.

Comment: I updated the first snippet for each item to be `complete` and added the code to show how to add the class and check the checkbox. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Almost. I meant for the item (text) to be crossed through when the box is checked. So a strikethrough of the text occurs when the box item is checked mark or checked as done.

Comment: Of course. added `setCheckboxes()` to first snippet

Comment: Thanks again! That was more code than I realized. Now I am on the right track:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234793/discussion-between-stephenw-and-kinglish).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 function renderTodos(todos) {
 //delete all the todos in the DOM
 todoItemsList.innerHTML = '';

 // insert todos
 todos.foreach(todo => {
 todoItemsList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
 <li class="item" data-key="${todo.id}">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" ${todo.completed ? 
        checked : ''}>
        ${todo.name}
        <button class="delete-button">x</button>
 </li>`)
  })

 }
```

first of all, you need to clear all the todos and rerender them,
try this code.

Comment: I just implemented storing the items to local storage. If you have time, how would I go about making the functionality to edit each listed item's text (input value) when clicked. I know I would need an event listener, and need to listen for input I think.  But that is all I know. Here is what I have so far https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/ExmZLeQ

Comment: You want to give the user the ability to edit the todos??

Comment: Yes, I would like to give the user the ability to edit the todos.